# Short satire about a comically upscaled spaceship

Tags: story-identification, space, online-resources

About 5-7 years ago, I stumbled upon a forum post with a few paragraphs written about a spaceship that started with the designs of a "normal" sized military type starship, and just scaled up the dimensions. It used that ship as an example of poor design.

Some specific details I remember:

- the windows in the bridge were hundreds of meters long, and had problems with cracking from the pressure
- since the ship was just "scaled up", sections like crew quarters were kilometers away from other parts of the ship, instead of being distributed throughout
- it took almost an entire workday to travel from the crew quarters to your station
- some crew eventually started camping out at their stations permanently
- the various crew departments of the ship eventually turned into factions that held their services hostage from the rest of the ship (sanitation, life support, etc.)

What I can't remember is whether the quoted text was originally from a book, or fan fiction, or an just an old forum post. I do remember that when I saw it, it was posted as a quote (not original content at the time I saw it), and the post implied that what it was quoting had been around for a while. I'm 99% sure that it was on a vBulletin or phpbb site, and not Reddit, but not a forum that I frequented, so I don't remember the name.

I have done a few searches over the past couple of years for fictional spaceships with huge windows and long commutes, but I haven't found anything close to what I remember. If anyone could help me find either the forum post, or any ideas on where to look for the original source, that would be awesome. It's kind of funny, but that one snippet of a forum post has stuck in the back of my head for years, and I'd like to find out if it came from a longer source.

Comment: Sort of like *Feersum Endjinn* except a spaceship, not a castle...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

That sounds like a meme from *Star Wars* about the continually increasing size of the Star Destroyers.

It's called the 'SDSD Freudian Nightmare' and ticks all of the boxes.

[image: Image of said meme, showing the relative Star Destroyer sizes and text quoted below]

> Maiden Flight, SDSD Freudian Nightmare
>
> Imperial Weapons Development Center, Coruscant To Whom it May Concern:
>
> To Whom it May Concern:
>
> Gentlemen, let me start by saying that I am greatly honored to be chosen for command of such a magnificent vessel. That said, our insystem shakedown cruise has turned up a few minor issues that I would like to see remedied as soon as possible.
>
> 1. We understand your desire to continue the classical stylized lines of the first star destroyer class vessels, and we appreciate your asthetic sense in that regard. However, strictly speaking, was it absolutely necessary to scale up the bridge tower directly? I must confess the foreward bridge window is a great distraction. Militarily, we feel that as is, the three kilometer tall window pane may provide too tempting a target for enemy forces we may engage. We've lost four helmsmen so far to vertigo as well, and we don't think this is in the best interests of the vessel's well-being.
> 2. The sheer size of our vessel, while a glorious symbol of the mighty Emperor, which we all appreciate completely, has become apparent to us all. My initial briefing tour of the vessel took six days to complete, and the travel tubes were based on the design in use aboard the slightly smaller Executor-class vessels. Travel time being prohibitive, we were forced to camp out in the corridors of the major sectors when we stopped for the night. Furthermore, since our crew quarters sections are located entirely within the aft dorsal sectors, both our Engineering crew and ground forces complements have built tent cities within their own sections, and are living there. Fire hazard has become nearly intolerable and the hydroponics department has sent me six hundred messages insisting that the smoke from the camp-fires is ruining their crop, and that we have enough food left aboard for only another three weeks.
> 3. Our vessel's own gravity is not being handled as well as could be done, with some minor problematical consequences. Our plumbers called my attention to the fact that the sewage from our 6 million-man crew backwashed through the air vents in Sections 42 to 78, decks 258 through 532. Malaria and dysentary broke out in those sections, and we were forced to cordon it off to prevent an epidemic. Our first Chief Medical Officer unfortunately was killed when he requested the paperwork on those affected, and upon receiving e-mailed reports from all 739 of his senior doctors, the computer screen in his quarters self-destructed, propelling shrapnel throughout his quarters. All droids who enter the area have failed to return, and a remote camera probe sent in, recorded images of the survivors in the affected area where they were flinging their own feces at each other, warring with sharpened pieces of metal, and attempting to eat the dismembered limbs of the aforementioned droids.
> 4. On a similar note, regarding the unfortunate loss of our last CMO, we have finally decided that the staff requirements of this vessel are creating further problems. For instance, our Chief Engineer has begun the habit of signing his reports, "Chief Marshal, Sovereign Nation of Ree'Ak'tor." He has since sealed off those decks, and started a war. The war in question is against his apparent rival, the commander of our ground forces near the main flightdeck, who has taken to calling himself "Bringer of the Apocalypse." Surveillance records indicate that they have since stopped wearing their armor, and have begun smearing their bodies with industrial cleaning fluid and lubricants before launching raids upon the Engineering department. We believe that they have begun ritualistically sacrificing one of our TIE-fighter pilots before each attack to bring them luck.
>    Aside from a minor note that some of our turbolaser turret gunners may have starved to death when their food shipments were cut off by the warzone, there is little else to remark on, save that in our first tactical drill, during the course of a two-hour right turn, we failed to halt our rotation with the result of the subsequent and very unfortunate destruction of the entire Coruscant 4th Defensive Fleet. I've made a note to send out letters of regret the moment we reacquire contact with our communications room at the bow of the vessel. That of course is the reason why this message had to be sent to your offices via pen, paper, and one of our probe droids. I beg forgivness for the clerical difficulties that may cause.
>
> Signed,
> Grand Admiral
> SDSD Freudian Nightmare

Comment: Also similar to https://alexanderwales.com/instruments-of-destruction/, about the difficulties in designing the Death Star II.

Comment: That's the one, thank you!

Comment: The biggest ship listed appears to be around 200 KM long which could be crossed in 1 hour with high speed rail. Should be easily manageable to travel to the other side every day. The 3 kilometer window plane mentioned could match the ship listed so I don't think the image is inaccurate.

Comment: @mousetail:  Never let accuracy stand in the way of a good joke.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert For sure. The scale issue doesn't harm the humor in this case.

Comment: The "slightly smaller" Executor class :)

Comment: This is what happens when either Disney or Marvel gets its hands on something.

Comment: Isn't part of the problem though that they're using a transport system from smaller ships? Sure faster transport methods are available, but seemingly weren't considered in the upscale approach.

Comment: I thought this was going to be about Spaceballs.